# Accessing a union "type" from outside the class?

Tags: c++, struct, unions

I have this code which I have written so I can atomically write a float and int together, as 64 bits:

```
namespace X{

template<typename P>
class MyClass<P>{
    public:

        MyCompStruct getStruct(){
            return MyCompStruct;          // Is this correct?
        }

    private:

    float a;                                                

    struct MyCompStruct{
        union{
            struct{
                float                       b;                                                   
                int32_t                     c;                                              
            };

            uint64_t                        composite;
         };

         operator=(const MyCompStruct& src) {
              this->composite= src.composite; 
         }
    };
};

}
```

but I am struggling how I declare so that I can grab the struct from a different class with ao object of type MyClass

:

```
X::MyClass<P>::MyCompStruct mcs = obj.getStruct();   // Completely wrong
mcs.b = ...
mcs.c = ...
```

Could somebody please help?

Comment: You mix together the types and variables/objects. These are two completely different things.

Comment: @NO_NAME hi, is there any way you could show me in an answer? Will gladly accept.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you want to do. Do you want to use `MyCompStruct` as a type or as an object? If the former, it is impossible to return type from function. If the latter, you even don't have any object of type `MyCompStruct`, so you can't return it.

Comment: In C++, accessing any member of a union other than the one last set causes undefined behaviour, so this whole idea is flawed from the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code

1. `MyCompStruct` is defined using template specialization syntax. Get rid of the extra `<P>`.
2. `MyCompStruct` is declared `private` so only `MyClass` and friends of `MyClass` can access it. If you want others to access `MyCompStruct` you need to make it public (or protected if you want to limit access to derived classes).
3. `MyCompStruct` is declared after its first use in `getStruct`. Declare it before it's used.
4. Your assignment operator has no return type and returns no data. This is wrong.
5. `getStruct` is attempting to return a type instead of an *instance* of a type. You need to add some parenthesis in there.
6. Stop using `using namespace std;`. It's just bad form. it's not in the code you posted but I can smell it.
7. `getStruct` doesn't appear to be a function that would make any modifications to the object. Declaring it `const` would be good for your soul.

Here is your code with all of the fixes for the issues noted above.I removed the namespace because it's irrelevant here.

```
template<typename P>
class MyClass   //  Removed extra <P>
{
public: //  Make it public

    //  Decalre before it's usage.
    struct MyCompStruct
    {
        union{
            struct{
                float                       b;
                int32_t                     c;
            };  //  Unnamed unions are a non-standard. Be careful.

            uint64_t                        composite;
        };

        //  Added a return type
        MyCompStruct& operator = (const MyCompStruct& src)
        {
            composite = src.composite;

            //  Returning this allows operations to be chained a = x = y;
            return *this;
        }
    };


    MyCompStruct getStruct() const
    {
        return MyCompStruct();  //  Return an instance instead of a type
    }

private:

    float a;
};
```

Basic usage:

```
int main()
{
    MyClass<int> obj;
    MyClass<int>::MyCompStruct mcs = obj.getStruct();
}
```

Now that all of that has been fixed you have a couple of options for `getStruct`.

In the version above it returns a newly created instance of `MyCompStruct`. If all you want/need is access to the type itself and all `getStruct` does is create an empty instance you can get rid of `getStruct` completely and allow others to directly create an instance of `MyCompStruct`.

```
int main()
{
    MyClass<int>::MyCompStruct mcs;
}
```

If this is not the behavior you want and you would rather return a reference or pointer to an already created instance owned (as a member variable) by `MyClass` you can change it like below

```
template<typename P>
class MyClass
{
public:

    /**** Removed unchanged code ****/

    // Return a non-const reference allowing others to modify the
    // contents of compData. If you don't want others to MODIFY the data
    // change the return type to const MyCompStruct&
    MyCompStruct& getStruct()
    {
        return compData;  //  Return our owned instance
    }

    // Return a const reference to compData. This prevents others
    // from modifying the data and allows them to access it with a
    // const qualified instance of MyClass.
    const MyCompStruct& getStruct() const
    {
        return compData;  //  Return our owned instance
    }

private:

    MyCompStruct compData;
};
```

Comment: Anonymous unions are standard. See [class.union]/5. However anonymous structs are non-standard.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Oops. Fixed

Comment: Are anonymous structs really non-standard? They've been valid C almost right from the start, so I'd expect the C++ standard to also allow for them. (Although... I think C did at least require you to have at least one of a tag-name or a declared variable...)

Comment: @celticminstrel anonymous structs were added to C in C11